# How to resolve “_this is undefined” in angular 4

Tags: angular

```
connect=()=>{
    this.api=new trovaSDK_Init("normal",this.businessKey,"user","user@gmail.com","","","",this.apiCallBack,this.url,this.port);
};

apiCallBack=(e:any)=>{
    console.log(this.api);
};
```

After compiling in `apiCallBack` `this` key word becoming `_this` and giving error `_this is undefined`

How to solve it?

Comment: You could try to define them.

Comment: Can you paste your full ts code here. I think you are using core ES6 class rather than typescript class.

Comment: export class ConsultationComponent implements OnInit { apiCallBack:any;connect=()=>{
    this.api=new trovaSDK_Init("normal",this.businessKey,"user","user@gmail.com","","","",this.apiCallBack,this.url,this.port);
};

apiCallBack=(e:any)=>{
    console.log(this.api);
};}

Comment: how are you triggering those methods? base on the code you provided, you are not calling them, you only defined your function.

Comment: it is triggerd as callback which is assigned in connect()

Answer (score 0):

In your case the context of `this` in `apiCallBack` is different.

Change your connect function as below.

```
connect=()=>{
    this.api=new trovaSDK_Init("normal",this.businessKey,"user","user@gmail.com","","","",this.apiCallBack.bind(this),this.url,this.port);
};
```